# python:print(''.join(doc.xpath('//text()'))

Tags: python

What is wrong? Please,somebody says me,what I have to write instead of  application/x-abiwordAbiWord.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> f=open('a.abw','r').read()
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc=etree.fromstring
>>> from lxml import html
>>> doc=html.fromstring
>>> doc
<function fromstring at 0x0113B858
>>> print(''.join(doc.xpath('//text()'))
      application/x-abiwordAbiWord

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you didn't close the "(" in your print

Comment: this is not a problem,problem is with "application"

Comment: *What* problem with "application"? What are you trying to do with it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a close-paren on the print statement. Also, unless I'm monumentally mistaken, your fromstring functions are missing parentheses and a parameter; according to the [python reference](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring), the function signature needs to be `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text)`

As it currently stands, it looks like you're assigning a reference to function "fromstring()" to "doc". You can't call ".xpath()" on a function reference.

EDIT: Try this.
EDIT 2: Tried to clarify in response to OP comment

1: paste this code into an empty document:

```
MY_FILE_NAME = "path/to/my/file.abw"
# MY_FILE_NAME = "C:\\path\\to\\my\\file.abw" ## use this on windows

from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
import os

f=open(MY_FILE_NAME,'r')
myStr = f.read()
f.close()

doc=etree.fromstring(myStr)
doc=html.fromstring(myStr)

text = ''.join(doc.xpath('//text()'))

f = open(os.environ["HOME"] + "output.txt",'w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

2: save document as recover.py

3: run the script in python

4: ???

5: profit! (aka, your story should now be in output.txt in your home directory)

---

Note: **What exactly are you trying to do?** If you give us a precise problem/task, people will be able to help you better. Also try to describe what you have already tried - SO isn't supposed to be a place where people do your work for free, so its important to show that you put in some effort to solve/research your problem.

Comment: I am big amateur,so this won't help me..I just do,what one boy do,but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can anybody rewrite it all?Please,it is very important.

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm trying about this : http://stephenmw.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/abiword_recovery/

Comment: I edited my answer again; what I posted *should* do what you are asking for. If not, post the exact error output here and I can try to help

Comment: @nikita23: I have tried Moritz's code on my linux machine and it work's perfectly fine.

Comment: for me too..but I have  damaged abw. file...in comments(http://stephenmw.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/abiword_recovery/),I wrote,what happend.

Comment: Hmm, that link doesn't work for me. So if you try to run the code above, obviously replacing "a.abw" with the full path to your damaged file, what happens? Does that not output the contents of your document?

Comment: Ok..my English isn't very good,but I try to explain:I wrote story in AbiWord.But one day,when I want to open it,it doesn't work (AbiWord cannot open /my file/It appears to be an invalid document).On http://stephenmw.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/abiword_recovery/ I found solution,but I am just amateur,I can't fix it.According to said website it's possible save my file and restore some lost data.

Comment: I've tried to make it even clearer. What part of "save my file and restore some lost data" is not working for you?

Comment: doc=etree.fromstring(f)=lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError

Comment: sorry,but your method doesn't work for me...when I run it in phyton,it opens,but after two seconds it dissapers..maybe I have also problem with phyton...I don't wanna be ungrateful and rude,but maybe when I send my file,you can fix it...I wish I can pay you for it,but I can't

Comment: It disappears when the script is done, so that doesn't have to be a bad thing. Do you have an output.txt file in your home directory? If so, what are the contents of that file?

Comment: problem is,that I haven't that file..I give up